# ogr2ogr cannot append of truncate PostGIS table

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr

I am reading in GML data to a specified PostGIS schema.
This is part of an automated job so and the db table might include views so I don't want to drop the table each time the script is run.

EDIT: It append and truncate works if I dont specify the schema. But in my workflow I have to use a specified schema.

Trying to do this:

```
Typical use case: “ogr2ogr -append PG:dbname=foo abc.shp –config OGR_TRUNCATE YES

ogr2ogr -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=geospatial password=postgres" \
    -lco SCHEMA=test \
    -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom \
    "C:\Users\my_GML.gml" \
    –config OGR_TRUNCATE YES
```

This result in `ERROR 1: Couldn't fetch requested layer 'â€“-config'!` ????

EDIT: Double dash is the correct way –-config OGR_TRUNCATE YES

In addition if I run a standard append version

```
ogr2ogr -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=geospatial password=postgres" \
    -lco SCHEMA=test \
    -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom \
    "C:\Users\myGML.gml"

ERROR 1: Layer test.mylayer already exists, CreateLayer failed.
Use the layer creation option OVERWRITE=YES to replace it.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `–config OGR_TRUNCATE=YES`

Comment: Did not work. I am running it from within jupyter notebook. Nad now i get Unknown option name '-config' .... Will jump out and try it in the regular command window as jupyter seem to cache som unexpected things.

Comment: Using --config OGR_TRUNCATE YES  as described in the doc for confg params: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions. Seem to be accepted. Still get the ERROR 1: Layer test.mylayer already exists, CreateLayer failed. Ignoring the append method

Comment: Turn out its because I use the -lco schema=<...> that it wont work. Need to find another way to solve it if I cannot specifiy my schema

Comment: use schemas=test in the PG params instead

Comment: Oh dang! missed the schema params in PG. That make more sense! It worked, thanks! Happy to mark it as solved if you make it an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you use `-lco schema=...` it prevents you using `--config OGR_TRUNCATE=YES` the answer is to use `schemas=test` in the `PG:` parameters along with hostname etc.